# How to make package of .exe file with required .dll and lib (opencv) files in visual studio 2010 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, dll, package

I have created an opencv project which include path having headers,*.lib and *.dll files of opencv in project properties and I have hard coded path of header files of opencv in .cpp that I have created.Let us say I need to give this project to customer,hence I only need to give .exe file of execution directly in customer system.

so please anyone help how I can do packaging of path of .dll and .lib along with my project .exe file. or are there any other way where i can send .exe file to customer which comprises of all i.e can execute opencv and also my logic in customers system.

thanks in advance and sharing answer is always appreciable.

Comment: do you want to distribute a binary(exe) or a project(code/sln/vcproj) ?

Comment: "I have hard coded path of header files" - ouch. that sounds like a total sockshot.

Comment: hey @berak, I need to send .exe file only and hard code means making headers of opencv to include in to my .c++ file.

Comment: If you only need to give an executable to your customer, then why do you want to include static library files (.lib)? Any compiled code used by your executable should be linked in automatically from your static libraries during the build process.

Comment: Hey @JBentley, thats not happening, the build .exe file doesn't comprises(linked) all those lib and dll auotmatically.

Comment: @santosh If you are able to build and run your executable (which from your comments, it appears you are), then the .lib files are linked and it is just the .dll files you need to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

Either use relative paths for everything you're using and ship them along (**if you're allowed to**, check the licenses first!!), or if you need to give your users the source code (as a VS solution) and you can't/don't want to hardcode the paths of your tools use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) to generate the solution files.

If you need to package binaries together along with your executable (and still, you're allowed to), you can use an installer packaging app like [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)

You need to make sure every dependency needed by your application is shipped otherwise your customers won't be able to run your software. To find out dependencies in a Win environment, try to use the **dependency tool** shipped with each copy of visual studio.

As a sidenote: you shouldn't be putting complete absolute paths in the include directives, e.g.

```
#include "C:\mysystem\helloworld\app\opencv\header.h"
```

because that is the sure recipe for compilation problems or unnecessary preprocessing when deploying or redistributing your sources. This doesn't apply to binaries: they just need to find the compiled dependencies/tools they need.

Comment: hey, thanks for reply,yea @Marco of course, i don't want to show my source code to my customer. and about the path hard coding,in my c++ file. I need to give the path for header files of the opencv(open source library).I have tried to built by putting the header file,.lib and .dll in debug folder of project still it's not working for me.i.e my .exe file is not packed of all above files.

Comment: can you run your app after you've compiled it? What error do you get?

Comment: i can able to run in my system,as i have installed opencv in my PC and *.dll that are present can pick up and run. but when I tried to install in my friends PC(which doesn't contain opencv installed) it's not working.

Comment: That is what you're trying to do.. then you need to deploy along with your executable all the openCV dlls needed. Use the depencency lookup tool to find those out and ship them along with your app.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010 Does not provide the package creation for C++.

In My Opinion you have to use third party software like 
`[Advanced Installer]`[1](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://www.advancedinstaller.com/&ei=uhlNU-qiI8mBrQehyIGwCA&usg=AFQjCNGOWi6OexMiQ6XX2G5iaqiBRGephg&bvm=bv.64764171,d.bmk) who search for the required `dll` and 
provide us to create the package as an installer.

And for the paths you have included in the Header.

If You Have a `.exe` then it does not matter for running your application.

Hope this will help you.